# How to dynamically set hosts in a play to a variable in a vars_file in Ansible

Tags: ansible, cisco

I have a play that defines a set of variables based on surveys, tasks are run including writing the variables to a file.  In a 2nd play I want to set the hosts based on a variables in the file.  It is giving me an undefined variable for the hosts.

```
--- 
- name: "Provision Routers"
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: '{{ DataCenter }}'
   
  vars: 
    customer_name: "{{ CustomerName }}"
    data_center: "{{ DataCenter }}"
    evpn_id: "{{ EVPN_ID }}"
    layer_3: "{{ LAYER_3 }}"
    ip_address: "{{ BVI_IP }}"
    prefix_mask: "{{ MASK }}"
      
  tasks:
        
    - name: "Config Router EVPN"
      iosxr_config: 
        lines:
          - evi {{evpn_id}}
          - control-word-disable
          - advertise-mac
        parents: evpn
        
------------------I'm leaving a bunch of tasks out to--------------------------
------------------Make this easier to read-------------------------------------
      
    - name: Make vars persistent
      local_action: 
        module: copy 
        content:
          - customer_name: "{{ customer_name }}"
          - data_center: "{{ data_center }}"
          - evpn_id: "{{ evpn_id }}"
        dest: /etc/ansible/group_vars/evpn_vars.yml
        mode: 0666

# 2nd play---------------------------------------------------------------------

- name: "Provision Switches"
  hosts: '{{ switch_group }}'
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/group_vars/evpn_vars.yml
    
  tasks:
  
    - name: Set switch_group to Commerce
      set_fact:
        switch_group: Commerce_Switches
      when: data_center == 'Commerce'
    
    - name: Set switch_group to Gumlog
      set_fact:
        switch_group: Gumlog_Switches
      when: data_center == 'Gumlog'
      
    - name: Set switch_group to Richland
      set_fact:
        switch_group: Richland_Switches
      when: data_center == 'Richland'
```

This is the error I get:

ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'switch_group' is undefined
The error appears to be in '/tmp/awx_929_h3cfbasn/project/provision_evpn_beta.yml': line 106, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.
The offending line appears to be:

- name: "Provision Switches"
  ^ here

This is what my variable file looks like:

[{"customer_name": "TEST444"}, {"data_center": "Richland"}, {"evpn_id": "444"}]

To generalize what I am trying to do, I need to set the hosts to a different group based on previous input in the original survey.

To add some more color, my first play is to provision a group of routers in a data center and the 2nd play is the switches.  I have them separated because obviously you do not want to push the same config to the routers as the switches.  If there is a better way to isolate the two groups (they do have different OS's) I am all ears.

Comment: Please reformat code to be more readable.

Comment: If you want to create a dynamic hosts group based on your tasks/conditions, see `ansible-doc add_host`.

Comment: I am not trying to add a hosts or groups to inventory. I am trying to use a different group of already existing hosts.  Is that not how module works or am I misinterpreting it?

Answer (score 0):

Your *switch_group* is bogus.

```
[{"customer_name": "TEST444"}, {"data_center": "Richland"}, {"evpn_id": "444"}]
```

It should be valid JSON. See

```
$ ansible-inventory -i "8.8.4.4," --list all
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {
        "hosts": [
            "8.8.4.4"
        ]
    }
}
```

Thus test via `ansible-inventory --list switch_group`.

Comment: This isn't an inventory group.  It's a list of variables.  I can set the inventory group on one of these variables and have some other uses for the variables down the road.

Comment: Whatever... you CANNOT have whatever content assied to *hosts* var in the playbook, that is your problem.

Comment: See what structure must have your inventory, ie. what you can use from your inventory as *hosts* https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts

Comment: I am not having a problem assigning hosts from variables as I do it in the beginning of the first play.  I am using a variable in the file to set the var to decide on the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get this working by setting the 2nd play to localhosts then using delegate_to to change the hosts.  It's not as elegant as I think it could be though.

```
- name: Make vars persistent
      local_action: 
        module: copy 
        content:
          - customer_name: "{ customer_name }}"
          - data_center: "{{ data_center }}"
          - evpn_id: "{{ evpn_id }}"
        dest: /etc/ansible/group_vars/evpn_vars.yml
        mode: 0666

- name: "Provision Switches"
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/group_vars/evpn_vars.yml
    
  tasks:
  
    - name: Set switch_group to Commerce
      set_fact:
        switch_group: Commerce_Switches
      when: data_center == 'Commerce'
    
    - name: Set switch_group to Gumlog
      set_fact:
        switch_group: Gumlog_Switches
      when: data_center == 'Gumlog'
      
    - name: Set switch_group to Richland
      set_fact:
        switch_group: Richland_Switches
      when: data_center == 'Richland'
      
    - name: Set port to layer 2
      nxos_interface:
        name: Ethernet1/2
        description: 'Configured by Ansible'
        mode: layer2
        admin_state: up
      delegate_to: "{{ groups[switch_group][0] }}"
      
    - name: Test nxos
      nxos_l2_interface:
        name: Ethernet1/2
        mode: trunk
        trunk_vlans: 5-10
      delegate_to: "{{ groups[switch_group][0] }}"
```

If I could delegate_to a group versus a single host it would work much better for me.  Or if there is a different strategy all together that I am missing.